# QML OpenStreetMap custom tiles

Tags: qt, qml, openstreetmap, tiles

I would like to use OSM plugin in my QML project. But I don't really like how default tiles which Qt provides look.

I've found out, that I can specify osm.mapping.custom.host for url string of a custom tile server. I also chose tiles ("Humanitarian map style") which I would like to use from tile servers list https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers.

I would like know, what should I provide in osm.mapping.custom.host field to change default tiles with Humanitarian map style tiles?

Comment: First of all, you should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Did you try to set the value according to the [Qt docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/location-plugin-osm.html)?

Comment: @folibis, I just tried again and found my mistake. I was setting http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/${z}/${x}/${y}.png to osm.mapping.custom.host, instead of http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/.
The topic can be close.

Comment: Add this as an answer, with a few more explanations and a code example. It will help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this is everything you need to write to add a custom tiles. 'Value' is on of the tile servers based on OpenStreetMap data (more can be found [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers), use 'tiles url' and don't forget to erase '${z}/${x}/${y}.png')

```
Map
{
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: Plugin
    {
        name: "osm"
        PluginParameter
        {
            name: "osm.mapping.custom.host"
            value: "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/"
        }
    }
    activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[supportedMapTypes.length - 1]
}
```